# I am making a multi level networking referral system and want some suggestions

Tags: php, codeigniter, logic, mlm

I am going to make multi level referral system which is not a binary system. If A is the parent of B and B is the parent of C.

If C do any action, some percentage will be distributed between B and A. I will use for loop for giving certain commission. But this chain be of 75 levels.

I think running for loop for 75 times will hang the PHP script. Should I break loop into 3 pieces or 1 loop can handle this?

I know this is not related to coding but related to logic.
Looking for some useful suggestions. I am working on CodeIgniter framework.

Comment: I have used recursion based on condition for exactly the same system.

Comment: I think recursion system can handle only upto some extent not for 75 times.

Comment: thats where your condition comes in .

Comment: loops in your application never run for that long , operations like update levels, distribute commissions, payouts etc we do in crons

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30570477/create-parent-and-its-child-tree-in-codeigniter this might help too